# Is it possible to store .PEM file on windows server store & read it programatically

Tags: c#, .net, x509certificate, pem, p12

Generally we keep .P12 (certificate) file on the windows server store. Certificates can be stored by using [this link](https://pubs.vmware.com/view-51/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.view.installation.doc%2FGUID-2D968AD7-ED62-46CA-B2B2-CCC526CA09F5.html). It seems only following extensions are allowed to be saved.

1. .P12  - Personal Information Exchange
2. .PFX  - Personal Information Exchange
3. .P7B  - Cryptographic Message Syntax Standard
4. .SST  - Microsoft Serialized Certificate Store

I have used OpenSSL and generated two .PEM files (private key & certificate) from my .P12 certificate. **Is it possible to store these files on windows server store?**

We can read certificates by:

```
     X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
     store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

        X509Certificate2Collection cers = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, "My Cert's Subject Name", false);
        if (cers.Count>0)
        {
            cer = cers[0];
        };
        store.Close();
```

Comment: What is the point? Why not using already supported `.p12` file?

Comment: I am using PhantomJs and I could not get it to work with .P12 file. But it worked with .PEM file.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to store these files on windows server store?

No, you can't, because Microsoft uses CSP (cryptographic service provider) concept when keys are loaded into provider and provider handles all operations with private key. Historically, CSPs use custom key format, which is not backward compatible with PKCS#1 or PKCS#8 key formats.

Your soultion is simple: use a pair of `.pem` and `.key` files for specific application. For other Windows apps use PFX or certificate in certificate store imported from PFX.